# Mongodb - Multilevel key:value pairs in a collection

Tags: json, mongodb, schema

I'm trying to store a collection with mongodb having multilevel key:value pairs i.e, JSON strings within JSON strings. Following would be the planned structure.

```
{
  a : b,
  a : {
          a:{
              a:b,
              a:b,  
            }
          a:b,
          a:{
               a:b,
               a:b,
               a:{
                   a:b,
                   a:b,
                   a:b
                 } 
            }
      }
}
```

Here a's and b's are different fields and will have more fields within it. I'm basically trying to avoid the use of multiple tables and have relational constraints as in case of MySQL and putting those in a single collection. I'm aware of the schema less design feature of the Mongo but is it a bad practice to follow the same?

Edit: An example of an actual use case : Stackoverflow
Questions having comments, Answers having comments, Vote for each of the same, timestamps etc

Comment: Horrible practice in the example you give. Nesting documents in the manner you are displaying makes it just about impossible to query in any meaningful way. You are best of explaining an actual use case with something close to actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell from the example you've given, but in general Mongodb is best for the type of situations you're describing. A couple times mongodb is super useful:

- When you have documents (think rows in a standard sql database) with a large veriety in the name, type, or number of fields
- When you have documents that will always logically be loaded within the context of other documents. For example if you would always load a user's address within the context of that user and never by itself, having it as a sub-document of a user makes sense.
- When both of these are true. Especially then.